# Transform results of estimator in a sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, xgboost

I have a sklearn pipeline that consists of a custom transformer, followed by XGBClassifier. What I would like to add as a final step in the transformer is another custom transformer that transforms the results of the XGBClassifier.

This last custom transformer will rank the predicted probabilities into ranks (5-percentiles).

```
Pipeline([
          ('custom_trsf1', custom_trsf1),
          ('clf', XGBCLassifier()),
          ('custom_trsf2', custom_trsf2)])
```

The problem is that the sklearn pipeline requires that all steps (but the last) should have a fit and transform method. Can I solve this in another way instead of extending the XGBclassifier and adding a transform method to it?

Answer (score 0):

From seeing the source code of [Pipeline](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/pipeline.py#L32) implementation, the estimator used to fit the data goes on the last position of your steps, the `_final_estimator` property of Pipeline calls the last position of Pipeline's steps.

```
@property
def _final_estimator(self):
    estimator = self.steps[-1][1]
    return 'passthrough' if estimator is None else estimator
```

where `steps` might be something like

```
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)),
 ('svc',
  SVC(C=1.0, break_ties=False, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
      decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf',
      max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
      tol=0.001, verbose=False))]
```

The `_final_estimator` property is just called, after fitting all the transforms one after the other, to get the estimator to be fitted to the model, see line [333](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/pipeline.py#L333) for details.

So, considering `steps`, I can retrieve an `SVC` class from it's last position

```
final_estimator = steps[-1][1]
final_estimator
>>> SVC(C=1.0, ..., verbose=False)
```

and fit it the training data

```
final_estimator.fit(Xt, y)
```

where `Xt` is the transformed training data ([calculated](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/pipeline.py#L330) before fitting the estimator) and `y` the training target.